# How to reduce CPU usage when having too many RecycleView's data in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm creating an app that requires a lot of input data from the user (update in milliseconds). Those data will be displayed on the screen by adding to RecycleView's data.

The problem is that having too much data seem to increase the CPU usage of my Kivy app (up to 15-18% even higher) and I'm looking for a way to lower the CPU usage in order to make my app as light as possible (CPU usage should be around 3-8%).

I am not sure if this problem is related to another field of app programming, can someone give me any idea to use less CPU when having too much RecycleView's data?

Comment: I think I figure out the problem, it's because my RecycleView was refreshing every millisecond to update the displayed values. That the reason why it's so much CPU.

Comment: Any other ideas about this article would be appreciated.